# Multiple assignments in filtered datasets

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to do multiple assigments with a filtered dataset I encountered a strange behavior I cannot explaim myself. My Testdata:

```
import pandas as pd
wert = 2.5
df = pd.DataFrame([['Test', 12, None, None], ['Test2', 15, None, None]], columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

My first question occured executing this line of code:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'Test'), ['D']] = df['B'] * wert
```

the filter is only on the left side so how does `df['B']` knows where to assign the values? I thought `df['B']` should be filtered as well but this is obviously not neccessary. So I stepped forward doing multiple assignment with condition and tried to execute this line:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'Test'), ['C', 'D']] = [1, df['B'] * wert]
```

Now I get an error `ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value`. My explanation would be that the array `df['B'] is longerthan df.loc[df['A']=='Test)` but since this worked fine in example 1 this cannot be the exlanation. Could anyone tell me why this is not working and giving me this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why does this happen?**

Because `pandas` will raise a `ValueError` when:

> the indexer is an ndarray or list and the lengths don't match.
>
> An special-case is allowed for when the indexer is a boolean array and
>   the number of true values equals the length of `value`. In this
>   case, no exception is raised.
>
> [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7f318658b92155678b31780722277d1f8c8df569/pandas/core/indexing.py#L2435)

You can use `df.assign()` if you don't want to filter `df['B']` to match:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'Test')].assign(C=1, D=df['B'] * wert)
```

Comment: There is same length but different index, so if convert to array it working

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, `df['new'] = pd.Series([4,5]).values` is a different kind of assignment/setting and will crash if length is not the same, `df['new'] = pd.Series([4,5])` is also different but won't crash if length is different.

Comment: Assigning with an `ndarray` where length `!=` `df.shape[1]` will still crash (on `v0.23.4`).

Comment: ya, try explain. Your statement is right, but not working here. It working like `df['new'] = pd.Series([4,5], index=[5,6]).values`

Comment: I failed with explanation, so ask in github.

Comment: Ok, this may be a bug but the reason is that `pandas` will try to set your entire item when you send in multiple assignments using `loc`. If you do `df.loc[(df['A'] == 'Test'), ['D']] = df['B'] * wert` first the indexes will be matched and only the matching value will be set, this does not happen when you do `df.loc[(df['A'] == 'Test'), ['C', 'D']] = [1, df['B'] * wert]`. Instead, `pandas` will then try to set the entire `df['B'] * wert` Series  which raises the `ValueError` in the way I described above in my answer, because the lengths are not equal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This was my intuition but now I understand why the code is throwing the error. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution working, if filter column `B` by same mask - is necessary same index values of filtered rows for alignment of data (not only length):

```
mask = (df['A'] == 'Test')
df.loc[mask, ['C', 'D']] = [1, df.loc[mask, 'B'] * wert]
print (df)
       A   B     C     D
0   Test  12     1    30
1  Test2  15  None  None
```

So if filter by another value:

```
mask = (df['A'] == 'Test2')
df.loc[mask, ['C', 'D']] = [1, df.loc[mask, 'B'] * wert]
print (df)
       A   B  C     D
0   Test  12  1   NaN
1  Test2  15  1  37.5
```

---

What means:

> ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value

Honestly, not understand error, so ask in [pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26783).

And add answer from pandas devs later.